# Mouse selecting autocomplete option - what javascript / jquery event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

In a standard textbox inside an html page, when the user types something that the browser then recognises part of and shows the 'autocomplete dropdown':

When this is selected / clicked on with the mouse, thereby entering the value into its textbox, what javascript event is fired?

```
        $('#txt').blur(function () { console.log('text changed'); });
        $('#txt').change(function () { console.log('text changed'); });
        $('#txt').click(function () { console.log('text changed'); });
        $('#txt').focus(function () { console.log('text changed'); });
        $('#txt').focusin(function () { console.log('text changed'); });
        $('#txt').focusout(function () { console.log('text changed'); });
        $('#txt').mousedown(function () { console.log('text changed'); });
        $('#txt').mouseenter(function () { console.log('text changed'); });
        $('#txt').mouseleave(function () { console.log('text changed'); });
        $('#txt').mouseout(function () { console.log('text changed'); });
        $('#txt').mouseover(function () { console.log('text changed'); });
        $('#txt').select(function () { console.log('text changed'); });
```

None of these work!

Comment: "change" will be fired when you tab or click out of the field (after choosing an option from the autocomplete). Note that even if they worked the mouse events wouldn't be enough since you can use browser autocomplete from the keyboard.

Comment: `this is selected`, you mean the autocomplete item from the suggested list ? what plugin are u using ?

Comment: The keyboard events work fine, which is why they are not part of this question.

Comment: @DidierG. No plugins, the browser natively implements autocomplete on the latest versions of chrome and firefox.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, the reason none of your events are firing is because you're attaching them to the textbox while the autocorrect list that the user clicks on is a separate html element. You need to attach the listener to the element the user is actually clicking.

Comment: Possibly, but is the the autocomplete box even a DOM item?

Comment: If you are referring to the browser built-in that suggests values you´ve used before then no. You will not be able to read those values as they are private to the user.